# Installing Noise On Ubuntu

Tags: music-player

I really want it on Ubuntu, because it's like itunes. I listen to a lot of music so it's nice to have a good player installed. It's called Noise, and comes pre-installed on Elementary.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use it too, and it's great! Just run these in your terminal.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install noise`

Comment: Please don't encourage installing a daily PPA just to install apps. Adding the elementary daily PPA is not recommended for everyday users; it's a PPA intended only for developers working on elementary OS and apps.